# how to get a value from a th tag containing a nested tag parsing in python?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

How to get a value from th without a value from tag a

```
<th scope="col">1926
    <sup id="cite_ref-2011CH_22-0" class="reference">
        <a href="#cite_note-2011CH-22">[22]</a>
    </sup>
</th>
```

I tried

```
 table = soup.find('table', {"class": "standard"})
 data_th = table.find('tbody').find_all('tr', {"class": "bright"})
 for tr in data_th:
     th_list = tr.find_all('th')
     for th in th_list:
         if(th.find('a')):
             print(th.text)
```

but in the end it turns out

```
1926[22]
1931[23]
1939[23]
```

and i need

```
1926
1931
1939
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approache is to select only the text of your target.

```
th.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<th scope="col">1926
    <sup id="cite_ref-2011CH_22-0" class="reference">
        <a href="#cite_note-2011CH-22">[22]</a>
    </sup>
   another text
</th>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for th in soup.find_all('th'):
    print(th.find(text=True, recursive=False).text)
```